# Uncaught TypeError: this.y.rangeBand is not a function after migration to D3 version 4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to migrate my code from D3 version 3 to version 4.

Here is my code for version 3:

```
this.x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, this.width]);
this.y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([-20, this.yItemsHeight], .1, 1);
this.xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.x).orient("top");
this.yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.y).orient("left");

...

this.svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return that.xShift; })
    .attr("height", this.y.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return that.y(d[that.columns[0]]); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return that.x(d[that.columns[1]]); })
    .on('mouseover', this.tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', this.tip.hide);`
```

Full code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvsh/18257mut/).

Here what I did during migration:

```
this.x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([-2, that.width]).padding(.1).paddingOuter(1);
this.y = d3.scaleLinear().range([this.height, 0]);
this.xAxis = d3.axisTop(this.x);
this.yAxis = d3.axisLeft(this.y);

...

this.svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return that.xShift; })
    .attr("height", this.y.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return that.y(d[that.columns[0]]); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return that.x(d[that.columns[1]]); })
    .on('mouseover', this.tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', this.tip.hide);
```

Full code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvsh/9xb85nay/1/).

But it still does not work with Uncaught TypeError: this.y.rangeBand is not a function at InvertedBarChart.initAxes (chart.js:330).

Could you please suggest how to change it?
Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For this error `Uncaught TypeError: this.y.rangeBand is not a function at InvertedBarChart.initAxes (chart.js:330).`

In **v4**, you need to use

`y.bandwidth()`

instead of

`y.rangeBand()`

Comment: @sparta90, now I have Uncaught TypeError: this.y.bandwidth is not a function :)

In this.y I have only this: https://yadi.sk/i/HEiiwxg13G8Nsm

Comment: @sparta90, sorry, I found another issue with y-axis definition, it was incorrect for InverterBarChart. Thank you very much, you are completely right.